# Show that $D(A)$ is dense in a Banach space $X$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let's consider the Banach space $$X=\{u \in C([0,\infty),\mathbb{K})\; ; \;u(0)=0,\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}u(x)=0\},$$
where, $\mathbb{K}$ is a field and $a:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow (0,\infty)$ is function such that 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{a(s)}ds=\infty,$$
with norm $||u||_{X}=\sup\{|u(x)|\; ; \; x \in [0,\infty)\}$. Set a linear operator $A:D(A)\subset X \longrightarrow X$, where
$$D(A)=\{u \in X \; ; \; u\:\text{is differentiable and}\: au'\in X\}.$$
In this context, the formation of law operator $ A $ is irrelevant.

I want to show that $D (A) $ is dense in $X $. I tried to do this by using a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem-$2^{nd} $ geometric form. That is, I tried to show that
$$\forall\:f \in X' \; ; \; f(u)=0,\: \forall\:u \in D(A) \Rightarrow f\equiv 0 ,$$
where, $X'=\{ g: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{K} \; ; \; g \; \text{is linear and bounded}\}$. But I could not finish this.

Comment: Is the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^x \dfrac 1{a(s)} \, ds$ assumed to be finite for any $x$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yes. Because the  function  $a$ is continuous. I forgot to put that information.

Comment: What is the topology on $K$?

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno the continuity of $a$ is insufficient for that to hold.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I can't tell.But I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I believe that this fact is not providential to the fact that $D(A)$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno What is the meaning of $C([0,\infty),K)$? You cannot define continuity of  a function with values in a set with no topology.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't know how to tell you that. Because the problem was presented this way for me.